# Subquery on Mysql 8.0.30 not working on Mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql, subquery

My query is working on MySQL 8.0.30 but when I run it on MySQL 5.1 I'm getting an `unknown column employee1.cfcodeno` error.

What do I change to make it work on MySQL 5.1?

```
SELECT 
    employee1.cfcodeno AS ID,
    CONCAT(employee1.cflname, ' ', employee1.cffname) AS Name,
    employee1.cfdesignat,
    employee1.cfcompany,
    employee1.cfgroup2,
    (SELECT 
        (IFNULL(SUM(nfamount), 0) - IFNULL(SUM(PAYMENT), 0)
        ) AS BALANCE
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            nfamount, 0 + 0 AS PAYMENT
        FROM
            cashoutkm.account1
        WHERE
            idpersonnel1 = employee1.cfcodeno
        AND dfdate <= '2023-04-13'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            0 + 0, nfpayment AS PAYMENT
        FROM
            cashoutkm.account2
        WHERE
            idpersonnel1 = employee1.cfcodeno
        AND dfdate <= '2023-04-13'
        ) km
    ) AS BALANCE
FROM
    cashoutkm.employee1
GROUP BY cfcodeno
```

Comment: MySQL 5.1 is stupid old. It's not a modern database and is missing a lot of things related to performance and correctness. It's also no longer maintained, and could have some very bad security issues. That is, it's _dangerous and irresponsible_ for the company to refuse to upgrade.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Except your comment is not helpful. Again: Please act on my comments. "[mre]" "the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK" PS Why do you have employee1 both dotted & not dotted with cashoutkm?

Comment: Reading the manual (5.7 [sic]) re subqueries: "13.2.10.12 Restrictions on Subqueries Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do it the following way. Instead of using a correlated subquery, generate two derived tables, grouped by the `idpersonnel1` in each case.

```
SELECT 
    employee1.cfcodeno AS ID,
    CONCAT(employee1.cflname, ' ', employee1.cffname) AS Name,
    employee1.cfdesignat,
    employee1.cfcompany,
    employee1.cfgroup2,
    COALESCE(a1.nfamount, 0) - COALESCE(a2.nfpayment, 0) AS BALANCE
FROM cashoutkm.employee1 AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT idpersonnel1, SUM(nfamount) AS nfamount
  FROM cashoutkm.account1
  WHERE dfdate <= '2023-04-13'
  GROUP BY idpersonnel1
) AS a1 ON e.cfcodeno = a1.idpersonnel1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT idpersonnel1, SUM(nfpayment) AS nfpayment
  FROM cashoutkm.account2
  WHERE dfdate <= '2023-04-13'
  GROUP BY idpersonnel1
) AS a2 ON e.cfcodeno = a2.idpersonnel1
GROUP BY e.cfcodeno;
```

Note I have not tested this, so I'll leave fine-tuning or debugging to you. This example is only to get you on the right track.

I agree with the comments above that it's alarming to see MySQL 5.1 still in use, since it was released in 2008, and end-of-life as of December 2013.